# How to create nested json file based on user inputs?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, rest, spring-boot

We are working on building a product. Please see below. 
Here each entity on left panel is a collection in mongo db. Once the user completes filling all the forms details, need to create a json file with key-value pairs. This can be nested to any level. One rootMenuItem can have multiple MenuItems. And one menuItem can have multiple children. And so on.

[image: screenshot]

This is UI page developed in angular Js. Each collection say `rootmenuItem`, `menuItem` etc will have save button to save the key value pair

```
{
  "version": "19.22.02",
  "constants": {},
  "gui": {
    "screenSaver": {
      "imageId": "ACU_screensaver/MBAC_black"
    },
    "menu": [
      {
        "configId": "test",
        "tets": "RootMenuItem",
        "icon": {
          "imageId": "teste"
        },
        "primaryLabel": {
          "rawText": "test",
          "textId": "tese.0216"
        },
        "intro": {
          "imageLayers": [
            {
              "imageId": "test"
            }
          ]
        },
        "children": [
          {
            "widgetType": "test",
            "configId": "21e88e",
            "children": [
              {
                "widgetType": "Tile",
                "primaryLabel": {
                  "textId": "test",
                  "rawText": "test"
                },
                "secondaryLabel": {
                  "bindingType": "test",
                  "deviceId": "test",
                  "serviceId": 1,
                  "serviceType": 40,
                  "ifTrue": {
                    "textId": "test",
                    "rawText": "An"
                  },
                  "ifFalse": {
                    "textId": "acu1.0236",
```

Multiple users can create and download this json file

We are using java spring boot micro services with mongodb

The problem here is how to create a json file from this data. Please check the sample json as well. What are the best strategies to generate json faster and store the file on mongo db.

Comment: have you tried `jackson` json-parser?

Answer (score 0):

1. First we will need a java object to which you can map the json.
2. then using [GSON](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide) we can convert the object to String.
3. and then can write the String json to file using Gson fileWriter.

Here is the example:
[Write Json to file](https://www.codevscolor.com/java-write-json-to-file/)

Let me know:)